# NSOperationQueue callback before an operation is started?

Tags: objective-c, nsurlconnection, nsoperation

Is there a way I can find out if/when an operation is about to start/execute on an `NSOperationQueue`?
I am using `NSURLConnection's` `setDelegateQueue:` and I need to know when it fires.

Comment: Would you be able to just set a delegate on your NSURLConnection?

Comment: Yes, but I didn't see a delegate method on NSURLConnection that is called before the connection is made. The earliest I found is when a response is received.

Answer (score 0):

In your NSOperation subclass add a copy property for a willStartBlock. At the beginning of main - before any other actions - call this block if it is set.

This way you can set up the actions to perform when the operation starts at the same time when you create the operation and before you put it into the operation queue.

The problem in your specific question is that you don't create the operations that are created on your queue. You can try to subclass NSOperationQueue and override the three public addOperation* methods. If you're lucky then one of these is the one that the NSURLConnection uses to append the callback operation to your queue.

Comment: I don't have an NSOperation subclass.

Comment: Read all of my answer. Subclass NSOperationQueue.

Answer (score 0):

May i know what exactly you want to do.

I am not sure what you want to achieve as it is not clear from your question but you can do something like that:

```
currentConnection = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:request delegate:self startImmediately:NO];
if (self.operationQueue) {
    [currentConnection setDelegateQueue:self.operationQueue];
}        
[currentConnection start];
```

NSURLConnection gets invoked once start method gets called.
You can also subclass NSOperation and override start method.